# How do we find the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

How do we find the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+x$?

$$x=f^{-1}(y) \implies y=(f^{-1}(y))^3+f^{-1}(y)$$

$$(f^{-1}(y))^3+f^{-1}(y)-y=0\tag{1}$$

At this point we need to find a $f^{-1}(y)$ that solves this equation. But how?

To provide some context about why I am asking:

if $g(x)=x^3$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ then $g$ and $f \circ g$ are differentiable, and $f$ is not.

In order for $f$ to be differentiable we need to impose an extra condition on $g$, namely that $g' \neq 0$.

$g_1(x)=x^3+x$ is such that $g_1' \neq 0$.

At this point I wanted to obtain an analytical expression for $g_1^{-1}$, to show that it is indeed differentiable.

Comment: You have a cubic equation. I suppose if you really wanted to write out the inverse it would be given by Cardano's formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula

Comment: Cubics do admit closed form solutions, but they tend not to be pleasant.  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y%3Dx%5E3%2Bx+for+x)

Comment: Do you really need an explicit formula for $f^{-1}$ ? Will it suffice to have an algorithm for evaluating $f^{-1}(c)$ for any real number $c$ ?

Comment: @Lubin I came upon this question in the middle of a larger problem I was working on, which I have specified in the amended question. The direction provided by the above comments is sufficient for me to realize that in fact it is not a simple matter to obtain this inverse.

Comment: You can show differentiability without an explicit formula, with the Inverse Function Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem .

Comment: Here is a full writeup of the question I was investigating when I asked this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463623/spivak-ch-12-prob-10-example-of-f-and-g-such-that-g-takes-on-all-value

Answer (score 6):

Since you have only one real root for the cubic

$$x^3+x-y=0$$ use the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) to obtain
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3} }{2}y\right)\right)$$ Just follow the steps.